# Closure of Lie brackets associated to Brown-Henneaux boundary conditions

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, lie-algebra

When we impose Brown-Henneaux boundary conditions to the metric field on AdS$_3$,
\begin{align}
  \begin{split}
   g_{tt}&=-\frac{r^2}{\ell^2}+\mathcal{O}(r^0)\,,\\
  g_{t\phi}&=\mathcal{O}\left(r^0\right)\,,\\
  g_{\phi\phi}&=r^2+\mathcal{O}\left(r^0\right)\,,\\
  g_{tr}&=\mathcal{O}\left(r^{-3}\right)\,,\\
  g_{\phi r}&=\mathcal{O}\left(r^{-3}\right)\,,\\
  g_{rr}&=\frac{\ell^2}{r^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(r^{-4}\right)\,.
  \end{split}
 \end{align}
and after the change of coordinates $x^\pm=\frac{t}{\ell}\pm \phi$ (light-cone coordinates), where $t$ is the time, $\phi$ the angular coordinate and $\ell$ the AdS$_3$ radius, it is possible to find the following asymptotic Killing vector components
\begin{align}
  \xi^t\left[\eta^+,\eta^-\right]&=\ell\left(\eta^++\eta^-\right)+\frac{\ell^3}{2r^2}\left(\partial_+^2\eta^++\partial_-^2\eta^-\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{r^4}\right)\,,\\
  \xi^r\left[\eta^+,\eta^-\right]&=-r\left(\partial_+\eta^++\partial_-\eta^-\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)\,,\\
  \xi^\phi\left[\eta^+,\eta^-\right]&=\eta^+-\eta^--\frac{\ell^2}{2r^2}\left(\partial_+^2\eta^+-\partial_-^2\eta^-\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{r^4}\right)\,,
 \end{align}
where $\eta^\pm=\eta^\pm(x^\pm)$ and $\partial_\pm\equiv \partial/\partial x^\pm$, in agreement with Eq. (6.5) of this [review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.07055). In this regard, if we define the Lie bracket $\left[\xi_1,\xi_2\right]=\mathcal{L}_{\xi_1}\xi_2$ associated with these Killing vector fields, I've been unsuccessfully trying (for almost a week) to show that the Lie bracket closes, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\left[\xi\left[0,\eta_1^-\right],\xi\left[0,\eta_2^-\right]\right]&=\xi\left[0,\eta_1^-\partial_-\eta_2^--\eta_2^-\partial_-\eta_1^-\right]\,,\\
\left[\xi\left[\eta_1^+,0\right],\xi\left[\eta_2^+,0\right]\right]&=\xi\left[\eta_1^+\partial_+\eta_2^+-\eta_2^+\partial_+\eta_1^+,0\right]\,,
\end{align}
which corresponds to Eq. (6.6) of the cited review. **How can I obtain the previous result?**

Comment: Have you checked this calculation using Modified Lie bracket? See the definition in equation (2.4) from [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.1541)

Comment: Here the asymptotic dynamics doest not depend on the fields, so there is no need to consider that enhancement.